# How to change Bibliography properties?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to change attributes of my bibliography file. What specifically I need to change is highlighted by the red rectangle on the picture. I need it to say "available at" instead of what is currently says (it means the same but in my language).

I searched the .sty file through and through but I cannot find it there. There are no options in the bibliography file itself and I dont know where else to look.

[image: this]

I am using TexMaker.

Comment: It's not located on the .sty, but on the .bst, that is the bibliography style you are using. What style is it? If there is a .bst file in the folder of your project, please upload it somewhere so we can take a look.

Comment: yes, there is a mystyle.bst file. I uploaded it [here](http://textuploader.com/dmre2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line 274 of your `mystyle.bst` there is a `format.url` function:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "Do\-stup\-n{\'{e}} z: \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Just change it to:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "Available at: \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

and you're good to go.

Any other predefined text that may appear in your bibliography should come from this file. Just find it and replace with the text you want.

Comment: I did and it did the work. However, when compiling BibTex, I get this error message:

_"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) _    (...)      _The style file: mystyle.bst A level-1 auxiliary file: prilohy.aux "�" can't start a style-file command---line 1 of file mystyle.bst : : %% $Id$ (Error may have been on previous line) Database file #1: literatura.bib (There was 1 error message)"_


Could it happen because I edited the .bst file in Notepad and the formatting has changed? It works fine (for now) but I dont want to leave it like this.

Comment: Hmm... The `"�"` you said may suggest that the Notepad changed the encoding, or there is something strange at the end of your `literatura.bib`, as the message suggested. Here, try [this one](https://pastebin.com/mFqc8xzp).

Comment: yes, that one works fine. it must have been the encoding. thank you!